# Elastic scale query with EF: Nullable object must have a value

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

On Azure, I have a setup of several sharded databases and an elastic query database with external tables mirroring the tables on the shards. The two main tables I use are:

1. Channels:

   - [Name] nvarchar NOT NULL,
   - [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
   - [ExternalReference] nvarchar NULL
2. Users:

   - [Email] nvarchar NOT NULL,
   - [FirstName] nvarchar NOT NULL,
   - [LastName] nvarchar NOT NULL,
   - [ChannelId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
   - [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
   - [AvatarId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
   - [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL

When I query this via EF and linq:

> var user = db.Users.Include("Channel").FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email ==
>   "tony@soprano.com");

I get an error:

> An error occurred while executing GlobalQuery operation: Nullable object must have a value.

This is what the User class looks like:

```
public class User  
{  
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = SequentialGuid.NewGuid();  
    [Required]  
    public string Email { get; set; }  
    [Required]  
    public string FirstName { get; set; }    
    [Required]    
    public string LastName { get; set; }  
    [Index]  
    public Status Status { get; set; }  
    public Guid? AvatarId { get; set; }  
    [Index]  
    public Guid ChannelId { get; set; }  
    [ForeignKey("ChannelId")]  
    public virtual Channel Channel { get; set; }  
}
```

Querying directly via T-SQL:

> SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Channels ON Users.ChannelId = Channels.Id

gives me the same error.

Further investigation shows that casting the Ids to uniqueidentifiers (which they already are) solves the problem:

> SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Channels ON CAST(Users.ChannelId as uniqueidentifier) = CAST(Channels.Id as uniqueidentifier)

The ChannelId and Id Columns are already non nullable uniqueidentifiers. The data inside the shards is also valid and not null, so what exactly is the problem here?

Another question: how can I force that ‘cast to uniqueidentifier’ in linq?

Comment: Can you show the class where you are storing each row from the result of the query?

Answer (score 0):

Quick question, you state that "Querying directly via T-SQL:
SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Channels ON Users.ChannelId = Channels.Id
gives me the same error." , are you querying from the Elastic Query Head database, or on a shard? I setup the schema and could not repro when querying from the shard, so I am wondering if I am not repro'ing the issue correctly?

Comment: I get the error if I'm querying from the Elastic Query Head database. If the same query is run on a shard, I don't get the error.